# I'm not able to install nginx 1.15 with PageSpeed module

Tags: server, nginx

I'm running nginx 1.14 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I just installed 1.15 following the instructions from this [Google page.](https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source)

`nginx -v` still outputs `v1.14`

question is...how do I enable the new version with pagespeed?

Answer (score 0):

You may set the version of `nginx` and `pagespeed` by adding the **`-n`** flag, i.e.:

`bash <(curl -f -L -sS https://ngxpagespeed.com/install) -n 1.16.0 -a '--with-compat'`

When building PageSpeed, I automate by using a script that can be found here:
https://www.majlovesreg.one/adding-pagespeed-to-a-running-nginx-instance

Note that this installs PageSpeed on a **pre-installed** NGINX running in your system. You may edit it based on your specific needs.